# Parsing a string (Unix Shell)

Tags: c, shell, unix

I've tried thousand options to parse the set of strings I store inside the buffer, but can't find a good way to store them string by string in the *args[] array of strings. 
What I want to do afterwards is to run execvp inside the Child process.

Thanks!!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_LINE 80

int main(){

char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
int should_run = 1;
int background = 1;
char buffer[1024];

    while (should_run){
            printf("jaime$ ");
            int i = 0;
            fflush(stdout);
            while (fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin)){
                    sscanf(buffer, "%s", args[i]);
                    i++;
            }

            pid_t pid;
            pid = fork();

            if (pid < 1){
                    fprintf(stderr, "fork() failed");
..........
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to split and tokenize the input string to parse commands to run with arguments?

Comment: You need to read more about the [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) system call, you're not checking for the correct return code.

Comment: Joachim, what do you suggest then for the fork system call? I'm following all the Operating Systems Concepts book instructions... thanks!

Comment: Etan, yes, that's right. I can't find a way to tokenize the input string. Going to follow some of the guys answers and see how it works...

Answer (score 1):

Code is not allocating memory to save the stirng

```
sscanf(buffer, "%s", args[i]);  args[i] is not initialized
```

Instead allocate needed memory.

Below uses `"%n"` to note the offset in the string at that point in the scan.   `" "` consumes leading white-space.   `"%n"` stores the scan offset in `n1`.   "%*s" scans just like  `"%s"`, but does not store the result.  Finally `"%n"` stores the scan offset in `n2`.  Now code knows, `n2-n1`, the width in `buffer` to extract.

```
 while (fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin)) {
   int n1 = 0;
   int n2 = 0;
   sscanf(buffer, " %n%*s%n", &n1, &n2);
   int length = n2 - n1;
   args[i] = malloc(length + 1);
   if (args[i] == NULL) {
     Handle_OutOfMemory(); // TBD code to cope with OOM.
   } 
   memcpy(args[i], &buffer[n1], length);
   args[i][length] = '\0';
   i++;
 }

 // use args[0] to args[i-1]

 for (int j = 0  j < i; j++) {
   free(args[j]);
   j++;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Chux, 
This is really helpful. 
I have two questions:

1. When I try to compile the program, it tells me that I have an "incompatible declaration of built-in function 'memcpy' [enabled by default].
It also tells me "undefined reference to Handle_OutOfMemory.
Any ideas?

2. Could you add comments on lines 4 to 9 explaining exactly what they are doing?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Jaime  Add `<string.h>` for `memcpy()`.  `Handle_OutOfMemory()` is a place holder for code you write to cope with the rare event of running out of memory.  Maybe print an error message and exit the program?  Post updated

Comment: Thanks Chux! Now I get it.  (Can't vote your post since I still don't have 15 of reputation, but will do it as soon as I do :)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing complex strings using the standard C library isn't going to be easy, nor clean.
This is especially true if you're trying to create a shell (which is what it looks like).

I would suggest taking a look at `lex` and `yacc`, which can be used to build tokenizers and parsers for complex syntaxes (including shell languages like `bash`).

Here's a decent introductory tutorial on [lex and yacc](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf). If you want to learn by example, you can check out [bash/parse.y](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y), although its grammar is fairly convoluted and complex.